# Illustrator exits isolation mode on file save

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, creative-cloud

When I am in isolation mode in Illustrator, and I save the file, it exits isolation mode. This can be a pain when I am within a group within a group within a group (three or four groups deep). The [Adobe help article](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-objects.html#isolate_artwork_for_editing) on the topic does not include saving in the list of ways to exit isolation mode:

> ### Exit isolation mode
>
> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Press Esc.
>    - Click the Exit Isolation Mode button  one or more times (if you’ve isolated a sublayer, one click takes you back a level, two clicks exits isolation mode).
>    - Click anywhere in the isolation mode bar.
>    - Click the Exit Isolation Mode button  in the Control panel.
>    - Using the Selection tool, double-click outside of the isolated group.
>    - Right-click (Windows) or Control-click (Mac OS) and choose Exit Isolation Mode.

On the top left here, you can see how I am currently in a group within a group. Clicking save will completely exit me out of isolation mode.

[image: Breadcrumbs]

**How can I prevent this behavior?**

Comment: If you save an Illustrator file while staying in isolation mode and then close it, next time you open the file will be in isolation mode. I think this is a kind of problematic behavior. Anyway, what do you mean with three or four layers down? Maybe a screen capture of your file and layers could help to find an alternative.

Comment: @Danielillo https://imgur.com/HkRKMZ9, on the top left you can see that I am in a group within a group. Sometimes there can be 3 or 4 groups, one within the other. Right now, if I save the file, it exits isolation mode.

Comment: Saving will exit "isolation editing modes" including Pattern editing, Symbol editing abd the Isolation mode. There is no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. That's just how Illustrator works. Sorry for the short answer, but that's all I have to say.

Comment: I am accepting this because it is correct for now; however, I have been told by an Adobe Community Professional that this is a bug and that it should be filed with Adobe. If the bug is resolved I'll post an answer here.

Comment: @MichaelKolber I can't recall a time when Illustrator worked differently. Keep us posted, but I doubt Adobe will fix this one.